# Finding minimum value of trigonometric function

Tags: optimization

Find the minimum value of $$\displaystyle \frac{2\cos^{-1}(x)}{\pi(1 - x)} , x \in [-1,+1) $$

Comment: Extremely sorry, corrected now.

Comment: (+1) What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you deduce?

Comment: Substituting $x = cos^{-1}(y)$ doesn't take me anywhere. I tried to simplify the function to differentiate it to apply the standard theory of Maxima-minima.

Comment: I have some doubts that an exact value can be found. Is this a problem from some calc book?

Comment: No idea, this was a question from my college assignment in Algorithm course.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock if this just for an algorithm you probably don't need the exact minima. A weak lower bound would work.

Comment: @Sabyasachi But the question seems to be asking for an exact value, not a lower bound.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock I doubt it. Wolfram Alpha is unable to find an [exact value.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+2arccos(x)%2F(pi*(1-x))

Comment: @Sabyasachi Oh yes! I forgot about WolframAlpha

Comment: WolframAlpha plots a graph for  ((2 cos^(-1)(x))/(pi*(1-x))) in [-1,1)

Comment: I have almost solved the problem. Can anyone tell me how WolframAlpha arrives at a Numerical Solution of -0.689 for [this equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%5E%28-1%29%28x%29+%3D+%28%281-x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%29%5E0.5)

Comment: May be : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method